# <KeyboardAvoidingView> does not work properly in Android nor iOS, same for react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I have this react native code, which you can see and simulate using this link:

```
https://snack.expo.io/BJn1NhnqH
```

*Dependencies and package versions can be seen in package.json file there

I tried to use < KeyboardAvoidingView > according to the documentation of React Native, it didn't work, meaning that when I clicked in the input field, the field didn't scroll on top of the keyboard.

After trying multiple times, I tried to use react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view, which also didn't work for my screen either for iOS or Android.

Can someone, after simulating my code using the above link, tell me where the problem is? Why is the keyboard avoiding view not working at all here?

Comment: Can you reduce your code to a minimal sample? Not only will that assist anyone trying to help you, it will also increase the likelihood of you finding the problem yourself.

Comment: @lxop Yes I can easily minimize the sample, but the thing is that I want to keep a picture, buttons and input fields on the same screen and making <KeyboardAvoidingView> to work, if I remove those the feature is working, what should I do in this case?

Comment: If your code starts working properly after you minimise it, then gradually add small bits back in until it stops working. Then whatever you just added is probably the problem